# Animate a button on a table row using Angular cause the whole row's button to animate

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

When I use this code in my table: 
HTML:

```
<td><button type="submit" ng-disabled="isMyProduct(item)" ng-click="addProductToMe($index, item)">submit
<span ng-show='addProdcutsToMeSpinner === true'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning"></i></span>
</button></td>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 $scope.addProductToMe = function($index, item) {
    $scope.addProdcutsToMeSpinner = true;
}
```

RESULT:
All the buttons from all the rows, start animating. I would like to animate only the specific button which tapped.

I thought that if I use this code:
HTML:

```
<td><button type="submit" ng-disabled="isMyProduct(item)" ng-click="addProductToMe($index, item)">submit
<span ng-show='addProdcutsToMeSpinner[index] == true'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning"></i></span>
</button></td>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 $scope.addProductToMe = function($index, item) {
    $scope.addProdcutsToMeSpinner[$index] = true;
}
```

RESULT:
No button is animating. 
What am I doing wrong?
What is the best practice to do it?
How can I reach the scope of the correct row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<td><button type="submit" ng-disabled="isMyProduct(item)" ng-      click="addProductToMe($index, item)">submit
<span ng-show='addProdcutsToMeSpinner === $index'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning"></i></span>
</button></td>
```

And controller:-

```
  $scope.addProductToMe = function($index, item) {
        $scope.addProdcutsToMeSpinner = $index;
    }
```

Comment: Or if you don't want method for this simple task than directly set **addProductsToMeSpinner** in ng-click like : `ng-      click="addProdcutsToMeSpinner = $index"` .

Comment: There is a server background process after pressing...thanks you!